# I can't put a picture, title and author in the same page

Tags: titles

I've tried to put a picture, title and author in the same page but I the command doesn't work. Furthermore the command \maketitle doesn't work now and I don't understand why. My idea is to aligne the picture in the top centre, che title right below centred and also the author, below title.

```
\documentclass[pt12]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{\textbf{Calcolo delle caratteristiche di un motore reale}}
\author{\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textbf{Gruppo:} & First Name \\ & Second Name \\& Third Name \\ & Fourth Name
\textbf{Classe:} & $5^{\circ}CI$
\end{tabular}}
\date{}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{Immagini/}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../../Pictures/Nautico.jpg}
\end{figure}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\afterpage{\pagecolor{white}}
```

Comment: A couple of things: You don't need `\begin{figure} .. \end{figure}` to use `\includegraphics`. In fact, in this case you don't want it. Further, `pt12` in the documentclass options should be `12pt`, and `\graphicspath{Immagini/}` should be `\graphicspath{{Immagini/}}`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 3):

You are designing a title page, so it's better not to try to fit everything in a \maketitle command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \pagecolor{cyan}%
  \afterpage{\pagecolor{white}}%
  \LARGE
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\\[3em]
    {\bfseries Calcolo delle caratteristiche di un motore reale}\\[3em]
    {\large
      \begin{tabular}{rl}
      \textbf{Gruppo:} & First Name  \\
                       & Second Name \\
                       & Third Name  \\
                       & Fourth Name \\
      \textbf{Classe:} & $5^{\circ}CI$
      \end{tabular}%
    }
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]